# More OpenMP threads running than set via omp_set_num_threads()?

Tags: openmp

I have a program that loops through a sequence of multiple for-loops (with other things in-between). Some the for-loops are parallelized using "#pragma omp parallel for". The number of threads is set via omp_set_num_threads() in the beginning.

It appears, however, that some of those for-loops make OpenMP to start a second team of threads and the process ends up with twice as many OpenMP threads than set with omp_set_num_threads().

What could cause this?

Comment: Yes, if for instance you have a #parallel inside another #parallel

Comment: I see that and I had checked before. But I believe there isn't such a thing. There are only "#pragma omp parallel for", no "#pragma omp parallel", and as far as I can tell, no parallel for loop calls another parallel for loop. It's all sequential.

Comment: Okay, it turned out that during initialization, one loop was executed in a different thread than the others, in a normal pthread, not in an OpenMP thread and no #pragma parallel inside another one. Seems like parallel regions created in different threads will have their own OpenMP thread team.

Comment: Glad that you have solved it